# Multi input keras model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to re-create a neural network mentioned in the following paper: "https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fneur.2020.00375/full"

However there's a lot of missing information. The neural network that i am trying to design:

[image]

I am a bit confused about the model above it doesn't look they concatenate the outputs from the 3 pretrained networks. It seems like they are using the imported networks as filters.

So my question is the following:

Is it possible to train 3 (4 with the last two dense and output layer) models seperately and use the 3 networks as filters. Pass their output (possibly flattened) to the last fully connected layers and get a classification and how is this usually accomplished training wise?

Or is the best approach to use the keras functional api to create a multi-input model where the outputs are concatenated before fed into the last neural network? (FYI: I've never used this api before so i don't know the limitations...)

Comment: As you mentioned there is a lot of information missing in the article, yet glancing through the article it does seem that they have train an end-to-end model where one input the PSDED image is pass through 3 CNN (the Inception-ResNet-V2, Inception-V3, ResNet152). The first fully connected layer of the two fully connected layers represent the concatenation of the penultimate layer (the before last one, i.e. the layer before the classification layer) of each CNN. In other words they use the CNN as feature extractors and combine the latent representation of each CNN into one concatenated layer.

Comment: Hi H so it would be something like the below where the imported networks is the inputs: https://imgur.com/a/jsjSMAA with the following architecture: https://imgur.com/k6gFzzR the example is from: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

Comment: Exactly! The only exception is that you are theoretically loading the same image as multiple inputs. But you need to use the appropriate input size for the CNN which is different for the ResNet compare to the Inception and InceptionResNet. So in practice you going to have InputA, InputB, and InputC with let's say InputA=InputB and InputC will have a different size.

Comment: If you have the opportunity, so can also train the models separately (each model on the dataset) and then infer the feature vector on the training set, concat and use it as a input for another training of the two layers classification.

Comment: Alright! thanks for the guidance! I better get started. For the record do you have any decent articles on how a loss function like the OHEM is constructed. They describe it in the chapter: "3.2.2.2. Loss function for EESC" https://imgur.com/XFCZbNC . I have read the article on it but it doesn't seem to be well-documented on the web ?

Comment: Do you mean how to implement a custom made loss function or the theoretical basis/rationale behind a given loss function (like OHEM)?

Comment: Hi i know that i gives an "advantage" to the results with highest loss by averaging the highest losses in a batch. However im a but confused since many builds a custom loss function and on sends back these losses that a top(k) but how is this better than categorical crossentrophy